# Cancel a user click on confirm box 'cancel'

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

This is probably a very simple question, but I can't find the answer, so hopefully someone can help?

How do you cancel a click action if the user clicks 'cancel' in a confirm box?

I have this so far but can't find what I need to fill in the blank.

```
jQuery('#doaction').click(function(e){
    if(jQuery('#bulk-action-selection').val() === 'delete'){
        var action = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete the selected User Groups? This action cannot be undone.');
    }
    if(action === false){
        { Cancel the click and don't delete the items }
    }
});
```

Comment: If user press cancel just don't do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if( action === false )
    return false;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#doaction').click(function(e){
    if(jQuery('#bulk-action-selection').val() === 'delete'){
        var action = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete the selected User Groups? This action cannot be undone.');
        if(action === false) {
           return false; // this would do
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `return false;` works, but returns immediatelly. `e.preventDefault();` might be more useful if there is some more work to be done before returning

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos `return false;` will prevent firing the default and also stop the propagation. `e.preventDefault()` won't work if there's any other event bound to it which does the **delete job**

Comment: in case there are another events bound to it, then `return false;` is a better choice, as you said. Since David did not said anything about other events, I assumed this was the only one

Comment: Thanks guys - as stated in another comment, I was under the impression that `false` was automatically returned if `cancel` was clicked, so it really was a simple question!

Answer (score 2):

Wont this work:

```
jQuery('#doaction').click(function(e){
    if(jQuery('#bulk-action-selection').val() === 'delete'){
        var action = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete the selected User Groups? This action cannot be undone.');
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```